# Using grouping to finding HTML elements via regular expression

Tags: regex, html

How does one go about using grouping in Regular Expression to find html elements?  The issue is when searhing a file, the < and > from javascript are found, so I want to always start with a < and end with either a > or />, or start with , then I want to look for stuff inside of that.  The key thing I am looking for is capital letters in element names or attribute names.

The reason I am asking is because I have been tasked with going through all the JSP pages and changing the uppercase elements and tag names to lower case.   I am simply trying to find a regular expression that is more accurate than what I am currently using.  The main issue seems to be that this regular expression does not know the difference between a < or > in Javascript and in HTML.

```
<[^!>%]*(([A-Z]{1,})|([^A-Za-z"'>=&\?][A-Z]{1,}[a-z]*))[\s=>]
```

Comment: Use an XML parser instead.  Regex cannot reliably parse HTML.  See this famous SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Unless someone comes along and prove me wrong I'm going to say that it's not possible due to the exact reason you mentioned. You, as a human, know that `<div` is the start of an html tag but `<100` is most likely not. But you can't create a rule that is not ambiguous to differentiate the two. For example, even if you use known html tags as identifiers the substring `<div` still has two meanings: the start of a div or less than the value of the variable "div". You can however use two regexes to resolve this: one to find `<script>` and the other to parse html outside of script tags.

Comment: Normally, I would be the one to say "With a small enough problem set, Regular Expressions can be successfully used to extract information from (X(HT)?|HT)ML"  This is not one of those cases.  You really need a parser, because you require an understanding of the language, and (X(HT)?|HT)ML is not a regular language, which means Regular expressions cannot successfully describe it.